# Qt resize image with best quality

Tags: c++, qt, image-resizing, qimage, qpixmap

Can anyone help me resize an image in qt without making the image pixelated.
Here's my code. the result is not as good as the original quality..thanks...

```
QImage img(name);
QPixmap pixmap;
pixmap = pixmap.fromImage(img.scaled(width,height,Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio,Qt::FastTransformation));
QFile file(folder+"/"+name);
file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
pixmap.save(&file, "jpeg",100);
file.close();
```

Comment: Do you shrink or extend the image? If you extend the image you will always have a "big" quality loss, since there is no more information for the new space than in the original image. Nevertheless every resize will be a loss in quality. There are quite a few algorithms for this all having different pros and cons.

Comment: Did you try using Qt::SmoothTransformation instead of Qt::FastTransformation?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have to pass `Qt::SmoothTransformation` transformation mode to the `scaled` function like:

```
QImage img(name);
QPixmap pixmap;
pixmap = pixmap.fromImage(img.scaled(width,height,Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio,Qt::SmoothTransformation));
QFile file(folder+"/"+name);
file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
pixmap.save(&file, "jpeg",100);
file.close();
```