# Qt Graphics: the painting of a QImage is very pixelated

Tags: qt, pixel, qpainter, qimage, qpixmap

I'm drawing my game's board using QPainter and QImage but it's very pixelated and I don't understand why.

Pixelated board:

[image: Game board]

Actual pictures used:

[image: Actual pics]

Code:

Loading of the picture part:

```
QImage desert_pic = QImage(":/images/graphics/pi.png");
c_mapicons.insert({type, desert_pic});
```

Painting part:

```
QRectF source(0.0, 0.0, 500.0, 500.0);
painter->drawImage(boundingRect(), c_mapicons.at(m_gameobject->getType()), source);
```

The pictures are 500x500 png files.
What I've tried (with no success):

- Using svg files
- Using `QPixmap` instead of `QImage`
- `QPainter::RenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing)`
- `QPainter::RenderHint(QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform)`

How can I get my pictures to appear smooth like in the second screenshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by resizing to the size of my tiles before painting. More details here: [Qt resize image with best quality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22652491/qt-resize-image-with-best-quality)

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use SVGs, here's a way to do it:
In your .pro-File: **QT += core gui svg**

header

```
#include <QtSvg>

class Board: public QGraphicsItem{

    public:

        Board();      
       ~Board();

        QRectF boundingRect() const override;
        void paint(QPainter *painter,
             const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option,
             QWidget *widget = nullptr) override;

        QGraphicsSvgItem *item;


};
```

cpp

```
Board::Board(){

    item = new QGraphicsSvgItem("folder/icon.svg");
    item->setParentItem(this);
    item-> ... /// set Pos() and so on here

}
```

You can set Antialiasing in your QGraphicsView as well, then all items will take the effect: QGraphicsView::setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing)